# installing a script as startup service in ubuntu

Tags: scripting, service, startup, ubuntu-10.10

I have a script `openerp-server.py` in `~/openerp/stable6/server/bin/`.I want it to be run at startup.(As a service or not - I don't know the difference)

These are the steps I followed

**1** Created a script 'openerp-server' with the following lines in `/etc/init.d/`

```
#!/bin/sh
cd ~/openerp/stable6/server/bin/
exec /usr/bin/python ./openerp-server.py $@
```

**2** Made the script executable by using the following command

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/openerp-server
```

**3** Made the link run on startup by using the following command

```
sudo update-rc.d openerp-server
```

I checked using `sysv-rc-conf`.And `openerp-server` was selected for run level 2,3,4,5.

Now after restarting I checked if the `openerp-server.py` is running, it was not running.

Please help.

Comment: Does the script run OK if you run it manually as root?

Comment: It works fine if i run the following command `/etc/init.d/openerp-server`

Comment: Then it seems to be a problem in the order in which the startup scripts are run, e.g. your script runs before a dependency like networking. Just move it later in the startup like robbyt suggests.

Comment: I did as robbyt said but still its not running at startup.Where is the log file in ubuntu to check errors ?

Comment: can you tell output of "which bash" command?

Answer (score 1):

You can drop commands like this into `/etc/rc.local` and they will be executed as the last stage in the boot process.

This is a bit of a hack however, you should check out the  [upstart tutorial](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/) to write your own init script (service)

Answer (score 1):

Use this commands:

```
sudo chown root:root /etc/init.d/openerp-server


sudo update-rc.d openerp-server defaults
```

Comment: I tried.The second command gives `System start/stop links for /etc/init.d/openerp-server already exist`.I checked if the script is running by using `ps ax | grep openerp-server` it gave `1962 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto openerp-server`.The `openerp-server` was in red.What does this mean ?

Comment: Try  this:   sudo update-rc.d openerp-server remove **and after** 
sudo update-rc.d openerp-server defaults

Comment: But if you want to run the script  as a process why not run it with nohup ?  Ex: nohup script_name &

Answer (score 0):

In the startup script itself, get rid of the ~ and use full paths.  Traditionally, `/bin/sh` is a very simple shell that does not perform tilde expansion.